# cant run my sql code, and error code is 1146

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1146

error code 1146

MySQL bench

```
SELECT email_address,
    count(orders.order_id) AS NUMBER_OF_ORDERS,
    sum((item_price-discount_amount)*Quantity) AS Total_ORDER
FROM customers
JOIN orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
JOIN OrderItems ON orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
GROUP BY Email_Address
HAVING COUNT(orders.OrderID) > 1
ORDER BY Total_ORDER DESC
```

Comment: It is telling you one of the tables in your query doesn't exist. Without details of the error and your database structure we can't really help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your table structure as a [mcve], see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query.